# Meteor Facebook can't authorize

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, meteor

my problem is that I can't configure server to work with Facebook properly.
Some time ago I had {{>loginButtons}} and at first login or after reset I had to copy and paste apId and secret into popup window, and now I'm trying to customize those buttons a bit more and I'm stuck with "Invalid App ID: undefined" after clicking on FB Button(windows popus up) and I even can see that in url I have undefined ID `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=undefined&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close&display=popup&scope=email&state=1111111111111111`

Here is a code, maybe you can help me or give me some other way to do it.
Basically I want to get rid of this registration form for normal users and keep Sign in fields for Facebook, Twitter etc.

My HTML:

```
<div id="login-buttons">
    <div class="login-text-and-button">
      <div class="login-button single-login-button" id="login-buttons-facebook">
        <div class="login-image" id="login-buttons-image-facebook"></div>
        <span id="sign-in-facebook" class="text-besides-image sign-in-text-facebook">Sign in with Facebook</span>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JS method:

```
"click #sign-in-facebook": function(e, tmp) {
        Meteor.call('facebookLogin', function (error, result) {});
        if (Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()) {
            Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
                requestPermissions: ['email']
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error when login with facebook " + err);
                } else {
                    console.log("login with facebook succeeded");
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

//this is on server side

```
facebookLogin:function(){
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
        service: "facebook"
    });
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
            service: "facebook",
            appID: "1111111111",
            secret: "1111111111"
        });
}
```

as you can see all data is in database

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()
    { "service" : "facebook", "appID" : "1111111111", "secret" : "211111111", "_id" : "111111" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit irregular. You're only supposed to enter the facebook configs once.

I.e

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
        service: "facebook"
    });

    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
        service: "facebook",
        appID: "1111111111",
        secret: "1111111111"
    });

});
```

Your login click handler:

```
"click #sign-in-facebook": function(e, tmp) {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermissions: ['email']
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error when login with facebook " + err);
        } else {
            console.log("login with facebook succeeded");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ye, code was a bit messy but it didn't solve the problem.
I don't know why Meteor doesn't see appID

Comment: @user3786592 Don't forget the client needs to see the app Id, even if it's on the server you need to be connected and the collection needs to be published before you can use it. Hence the need to add it in once off long before (instead of when the button is clicked)

Comment: I subscribed it to the client with 
Meteor.publish("loginOptions", function() {
        return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.find();
    }); , subscribed it on client side and still no ID

Answer (score 0):

Try to use both keys: clientId and appId (Some time ago facebook rename it to clientId) as follow:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
  service: "facebook"
  }, {
    $set: {
       appId: '11111',
       clientId: '11111',    // <-- Same as appId
       loginStyle: "popup",
       secret: '22222'
    }
 });
```